FastAPI on running getting error Invalid args for response field
# fastapi_app/ticket_management/routes.py
from fastapi import APIRouter, Depends, HTTPException
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from .schema import TicketCreate, TicketResponse, TicketListResponse
from .service import create_ticket, get_tickets, get_ticket_details, add_comment
from .dal import get_user_by_token
from connection import get_db

router = APIRouter()


@router.post("/", response_model=TicketResponse)
def create_ticket_api(ticket: TicketCreate, db: Session = Depends(get_db), token: str = Depends(get_user_by_token)) -> TicketResponse:
    return create_ticket(db, ticket, token)


# fastapi_app/ticket_management/dal.py
import requests
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from db import User, Ticket
from .schema import TicketCreate, TicketResponse, TicketListResponse
from config import JWT_VALIDATION_URL, JIRA_API_URL

def get_user_by_token(db: Session, token: str) -> User:
    response = requests.get(JWT_VALIDATION_URL, headers={"Authorization": f"Bearer {token}"})
    response.raise_for_status()
    user_data = response.json()
    return user_data["user_external_id"]

def create_user_if_not_exists(db: Session, token: str) -> User:
    user_external_id = get_user_by_token(db, token)
    user = db.query(User).filter(User.external_id == user_external_id).first()
    if not user:
        user = User(external_id=user_external_id)
        db.add(user)
        db.commit()
        db.refresh(user)
    return user

def create_ticket_dal(db: Session, ticket: TicketCreate, user: User) -> TicketResponse:
    new_ticket = Ticket(
        user_id=user.id,
        subject=ticket.subject,
        short_description=ticket.short_description,
        description=ticket.description,
        status="open",
        created_at=datetime.utcnow()
    )
    db.add(new_ticket)
    db.commit()
    db.refresh(new_ticket)
    return TicketResponse.from_orm(new_ticket)


I am getting this error
File "/home/aviox/Documents/code/Omar---Jasvir-Rexett-Support-backend/support_backend/ticket_management/routes.py", line 13, in 
def create_ticket_api(ticket: TicketCreate, db: Session = Depends(get_db), token: str = Depends(get_user_by_token)) -> TicketResponse:
fastapi.exceptions.FastAPIError: Invalid args for response field! Hint: check that <class 'sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session'> is a valid Pydantic field type. If you are using a return type annotation that is not a valid Pydantic field (e.g. Union[Response, dict, None]) you can disable generating the response model from the type annotation with the path operation decorator parameter response_model=None. Read more: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/response-model/

You haven't included create_ticket, so it's rather hard to say what you're missing - but it seems like you're returning the session itself, and not the object that you've added to the session.

We also need to see the code for TicketResponse. Looks like you might have a SQLAlchemy seesion as a field there?

yes you are right we have resolved this error thanks
